# How to partition and find the most latest value in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partition, database-partitioning

I have a table as follows:

```
ID   | col1 | Date Time
1    | WA   | 2/11/20
1    | CI   | 1/11/20
2    | CI   | 2/11/20
2    | WA   | 3/11/20
3    | WA   | 2/10/20
3    | WA   | 1/11/20
3    | WA   | 2/11/20
4    | WA   | 1/10/20
4    | CI   | 2/10/20
4    | SA   | 3/10/20
```

I want to find all ID values for which col1 had some other value in addition to WA as well and the most latest value in col1 should be 'WA'. i.e. from the sample data above , only ID values 1 & 2 should be returned. Because both of those have an additional value (i.e., CI) in additon to WA, but still the most latest value for them is WA.

How do I get that??

FYI, there could be some IDs that don't have WA value at all. I want to eliminate them. Also those that only have WA value, I want to eliminate those as well.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select distinct id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        last_value(col1) over(partition by id oder by datetime) last_col1,
        min(col1) over(partition by id) min_col1,
        max(col1) over(partition by id) max_col1
    from mytable t
) t
where last_col1 = 'WA' and min_col1 <> max_col1
```

The inner query uses `last_value()` to recover the *last* value of `col1` for the given `id`, and computes the min and max values in the same partition.

Then, the outer query filters on `id`s whose last value is `'WA'` and that have at least two distinct values (which is phrased as the inequality of the min and max value).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(col1) <> max(col1) and -- at least two different values
       max(case when col1 = 'WA' then datetime end) = max(datetime)   -- last is WA
```